# Extract and format data with `cut` and `awk`

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk, cut

I have the below file in txt:

```
"Firstname","Lastname","Company"
"Alex","Johnson","Alex Corp."
"Baran","Atasoy","Gülerler Ltd."
```

I would like to extract and format data by using `awk` and/or `cut` and have the format below:

```
Firstname Lastname
Alex Johnson
Baran Atasoy
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Use `awk` to split the fields on the `,` (`-F,`) and substitute out the `"` (`gsub`):

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/"/,""); print $1,$2}' file
Firstname Lastname
Alex Johnson
Baran Atasoy
```

Answer (score 2):

You could assign multiplay field separator by `-F`

```
awk -F[\",] '{print $2,$5}
```

Same with `sed`

```
sed 's/"\|,[^,]\+$//g;s/,/ /'
```

or

```
sed -E 's/"(\w+)","(\w+).*/\1 \2/'
```

Same with `tr` and `cut`

```
tr -s ',"' ' ' | cut -d" " -f2-3
```

At last but not a last: just `bash builtin's`

```
while IFS=, read a b c 
do
  echo "${a//\"/} ${b//\"/}"
done
```

Or may be more complicable

```
while IFS=[,\"] read a b c d f g
do
  echo $b $f
done
```